# Transforming Missing Column Data from Available Data from same column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill the missing data in my pandas data frame. However this data can only be filled in a certain non-traditional way. First I've marked missing data with -1, so what i want is to replace value of -1 in a certain way.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 11 |
| 99 | -1 |
| 43 | 34 |
| 23 | -1 |
| 65 | -1 |
| 17 | 42 |
| 12 | 66 |
| 99 | -1 |
| 43 | 22 |
| 23 | -1 |
| 65 | -1 |
| 17 | 42 |

I want to replace every missing value or -1 with next available positive value from the same column.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 11 |
| 99 | 34 |
| 43 | 34 |
| 23 | 42 |
| 65 | 42 |
| 17 | 42 |
| 12 | 66 |
| 99 | 22 |
| 43 | 22 |
| 23 | 42 |
| 65 | 42 |
| 17 | 42 |

I am able to attain the desired output if number of continuous -1s remain constant using `df['col].shift(1)` however that won't work because here placement of -1s are random.

Data size i am dealing with is fairly large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `replace` with `bfill` for this.

```py
df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnB'].replace(-1, method='bfill')

print(df)
```

```
Sample Output
    ColumnA  ColumnB
0        12       11
1        99       34
2        43       34
3        23       42
4        65       42
5        17       42
6        12       66
7        99       22
8        43       22
9        23       42
10       65       42
11       17       42
```

Answer (score 2):

use `replace()`+`bfill()`:

```
df['Column B']=df['Column B'].replace(-1,float('nan')).bfill(downcast='infer')
```

output of `df`:

```
  Column A  Column B
0   12      11
1   99      34
2   43      34
3   23      42
4   65      42
5   17      42
6   12      66
7   99      22
8   43      22
9   23      42
10  65      42
11  17      42
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Series.bfill`

```
In [24]: s = pd.Series([11, -1, 34, -1, -1, 42, 66, -1, 22, -1, -1, 42])

In [26]: s.replace({-1: np.nan}).bfill()
Out[26]:
0     11.0
1     34.0
2     34.0
3     42.0
4     42.0
5     42.0
6     66.0
7     22.0
8     22.0
9     42.0
10    42.0
11    42.0
dtype: float64
```